# Replace CRLF with LF in Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x

I've tried searching the web, and a number of different things I've read on the web, but don't seem to get the desired result.

I'm using Windows 7 and Python 3.6.

I'm connecting to an Oracle db with cx_oracle and creating a text file with the query results. The file that is created (which I'll call my_file.txt to make it easy) has 3688 lines in it all with CRLF which needs to be converted to the unix LF.

If I run python crlf.py my_file.txt it is all converted correctly & there is no issues, but that means I need to run another command manually which I do not want to do.

So I tried adding the code below to my file.

```
filename = "NameOfFileToBeConverted"
fileContents = open(filename,"r").read()
f = open(filename,"w", newline="\n")
f.write(fileContents)
f.close()
```

This does convert the majority of the CRLF to LF but @ line 3501 it has a NUL character 3500 times on the one line followed by a row of data from the database & it ends with the CRLF, every line from here on still has the CRLF.

So with that not working, I removed it and then tried

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen("crlf.py "+ filename, shell=True)
```

I also tried using

```
import os
os.system("crlf.py "+ filename)
```

The "+ filename" in the two examples above is just providing the filename that is created during the data extract.

I don't know what else to try from here.

Comment: Why not use the correct newline when generating the file in the first place?

Comment: This is what I have used when writing the file

`csv.writer(open("D:/Users/username/Desktop/EXTRACT_INPUT_"+dt_today+".txt","w"), delimiter=",", lineterminator="\n")`


the \n is the correct newline isn't it?

Answer (score 6):

## Convert Line Endings in-place (with Python 3)

#### Windows to Linux/Unix

Here is a short script for directly converting **Windows line endings** (`\r\n` also called `CRLF`) to **Linux/Unix line endings** (`\n` also called `LF`) in-place (without creating an extra output file):

```
# replacement strings
WINDOWS_LINE_ENDING = b'\r\n'
UNIX_LINE_ENDING = b'\n'

# relative or absolute file path, e.g.:
file_path = r"c:\Users\Username\Desktop\file.txt"

with open(file_path, 'rb') as open_file:
    content = open_file.read()

content = content.replace(WINDOWS_LINE_ENDING, UNIX_LINE_ENDING)

with open(file_path, 'wb') as open_file:
    open_file.write(content)
```

#### Linux/Unix to Windows

Just swap the line endings to `content.replace(UNIX_LINE_ENDING, WINDOWS_LINE_ENDING)`.

---

#### Code Explanation

- **Important: Binary Mode** We need to make sure that we open the file both times in binary mode (`mode='rb'` and `mode='wb'`) for the conversion to work.

  When opening files in text mode (`mode='r'` or `mode='w'` without `b`), the platform's native line endings (`\r\n` on Windows and `\r` on old Mac OS versions) are automatically converted to Python's Unix-style line endings: `\n`. So the call to `content.replace()` couldn't find any line endings to replace.

  In binary mode, no such conversion is done.
- **Binary Strings** In Python 3, if not declared otherwise, strings are stored as Unicode (`UTF-8`). But we open our files in binary mode - therefore we need to add `b` in front of our replacement strings to tell Python to handle those strings as binary, too.
- **Raw Strings** On Windows the path separator is a backslash `\` which we would need to escape in a normal Python string with `\\`. By adding `r` in front of the string we create a so called raw string which doesn't need any escaping. So you can directly copy/paste the path from Windows Explorer.
- **Alternative** We open the file twice to avoid the need of repositioning the file pointer. We also could have opened the file once with `mode='rb+'` but then we would have needed to move the pointer back to start after reading its content (`open_file.seek(0)`) and truncate its original content before writing the new one (`open_file.truncate(0)`).

  Simply opening the file again in write mode does that automatically for us.

Cheers and happy programming,
winklerrr

Comment: I was having so many issues working with windows based files and the line feeds and such, I was baffled until I came across your post.  Until I found your answer I wanted to pull out my hair.