# Python Remove line breaks from CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, line-breaks

When opening my CSV file in Notepad++ it shows the encoding is ANSI, and the line breaks are showing as LF.  I'm trying to remove these line breaks via python, but have not found a solution.  A couple solutions I've tried:

```
with open(csvTable, 'r') as f:
    raw_csv = f.read()
    clean_csv = raw_csv.strip()

with open(csvTable2, 'w') as f:
    f.write(clean_csv)
```

And:

```
data_set = pd.read_csv(data_file,skip_blank_lines=True, encoding='ANSI')
data_set.to_csv(target_file,index=False)
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: If you remove all line breaks you would end up with a single line?  Can you show an example of input and output

Answer (score 1):

You can (and should) use the csv module for any CSV-related work; beyond allowing you to control the lineterminator, it will also preserve the internal line breaks that may exist inside a "cell".

The following:

- opens your input CSV and creates an output CSV, both with the CP-1252 (Windows-1252 or "ANSI") encoding
- the `newline=""` directive tells the file handlers created by open() not to do anything with newlines as the files are being read and written; the csv module's reader and writer will handle all newline characters
- importantly, newlines inside a cell will be left as is, while the newline at the end of a row (the "line terminator") will be set CRLF with `lineterminator="\r\n"`

```py
import csv

ANSI = "cp1252"

with (
    open("input.csv", encoding=ANSI, newline="") as f_in,
    open("output.csv", "w", encoding=ANSI, newline="") as f_out,
):
    reader = csv.reader(f_in)
    writer = csv.writer(f_out, lineterminator="\r\n")
    for row in reader:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Here's my input.csv:

```
Col1,Col2
"à
ÿ",1
b,2
c,3
```

Looking at it from hexdump:

```
00000000  43 6f 6c 31 2c 43 6f 6c  32 0a 22 e0 0a ff 22 2c  |Col1,Col2."�.�",|
00000010  31 0a 62 2c 32 0a 63 2c  33                       |1.b,2.c,3|
00000019
```

we can see that we have LF (0a) for the line terminators, and the à and ÿ characters are encoded as e0 and ff, according to CP-1252.

Here's ouptut.csv:

```
Col1,Col2
"à
ÿ",1
b,2
c,3
```

Looks to the same to the naked eye; here's how it looks from hexdump:

```
00000000  43 6f 6c 31 2c 43 6f 6c  32 0d 0a 22 e0 0a ff 22  |Col1,Col2.."�.�"|
00000010  2c 31 0d 0a 62 2c 32 0d  0a 63 2c 33 0d 0a        |,1..b,2..c,3..|
0000001e
```

We can see:

- the à and ÿ are still encoded as e0 and ff, the CP-1252 encoding was kept
- the internal newline between à and ÿ was kept as 0a (LF)
- the line terminators were converted to 0d 0a (CRLF)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this post to create a solution: [Replace CRLF with LF in Python 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47178459/replace-crlf-with-lf-in-python-3-6) it also helped me get over the hump and provided an understanding of what was happening underneath the hood.

```
OldFile=r"c:\Test\input.csv"
NewFile=r"C:\Test\output.csv"

#reading it in as binary keeps the cr lf in windows as is
with (
    open(OldFile, 'rb') as f_in,
    open(NewFile, 'wb') as f_out,
):


FileContent = f_in.read()

#removing all line breaks including the ones after the carriage return
oldLineFeed = b'\n'
newLineFeed = b''

FileContent = FileContent.replace(oldLineFeed, newLineFeed)

#only have a carriage return now at the end of each true line, added back in the line break 
oldLineFeed = b'\r'
newLineFeed = b'\r\n'
FileContent = FileContent.replace(oldLineFeed, newLineFeed)

f_out.write(FileContent)

f_in.close()
f_out.close()
```